# Hover panel of some web page in search result shows blank preview screen

Tags: search-results, publishing-page

I have just received screen shots from client with some explanation.

When a user search for a term say 'Leave', search results page list all the web publishing pages.

Now the problem is there is 1 page which shows blank or empty preview screen when hover, but things are fine for others.

I do not have any access to machine or site to investigate what's causing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing incremental crawl, the problem got solved.